# Are there any other login products similar to LoginRadius?

Tags: authentication, openid, social-login

I'm thinking of using [LoginRadius](https://www.loginradius.com/) social site login/registration solution to integrate with traditional login/registration system. Has anyone ever used it and have any opinion about its performance and know of any other similar products/services?

Answer (score 3):

I do not have an opinion to pass along to you. Neither do I have any comment on performance. Obviously the products/service your looking at is in beta. Also note that some CMS have this built in or have extensions you can add for social login or sso. Here is some more info and providers:

- http://gigya.com/social-login/
- http://janrain.com/products/engage/social-login/
- http://www.oneall.com/services/single-sign-on/
- http://www.lanoba.com/social-login
- http://loginradius.com
- for Wordpress: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oa-social-login/
- for Drupal: http://drupal.org/project/sociallogin
- for Joomla: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/19293
- for Django: http://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/review-of-4-django-social-auth-apps/

just info

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_login
- http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/19/facebook-twitter-google-wordpress/

Comment: Re login/registration together and with social login but can create different username on our site, I just came across a popular site today that does just what I had in mind. Login in with Google the first time and you get a registration page where you can create a username for that site:

http://screencast.com/t/hqu58utqZ